# how do i set the login page to be the first page i land on without the main menu in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, layout

This is the code i have in my Main Layout but i don't want these pages to appear in my **Login Page** that i want to make the first page that appears in my application. I want the menu to appear after login.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font:bold;">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vehicles", "Vehicles","Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("VehicleTrips","VehicleTrips","Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Report","Index","Report")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("OffVehicles", "OffVehicles", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("MovingState", "MovingState", "Home")</li>
   </ul>
   @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
</div>
```

Comment: don't use layout for login page

Comment: @Imad is correct also login page should always have different layout this should be different from rest of pages.

Comment: thanks guys @Imad  I'm new at this... so now i'll just create a new layout for my login if you have any links that i can look  at to learn more please share with me.

Comment: thanks guys @SuprabhatBiswal  I'm new at this... so now i'll just create a new layout for my login if you have any links that i can look  at to learn more please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to share the layout you could simply use `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` in your view as follows:

```
@if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) { 
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="font:bold;">
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Vehicles", "Vehicles","Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("VehicleTrips","VehicleTrips","Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Report","Index","Report")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("OffVehicles", "OffVehicles", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("MovingState", "MovingState", "Home")</li>
   </ul>
}
```

This would hide the navigation for unauthenticated users.

Comment: Thank you @hutchonoid it did hide the menu :)